# Use partial view to generate dynamic form data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In my app I want to generate ViewModel's Attribute list using **PartialView**, but I can add only single one, because after adding another it gets put in the place of previous one. Is there a way to do this using **PartialView/ViewComponents** or any other thing?
View with no attributes:
[image]
When adding first attribute:
[image]
When adding second one the first one is not visible:
[image]

```
@model ProviderViewModel
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Url)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Url)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.Label("Attributes")
    </div>
    @if (Model.Attributes.Count > 0)
    {
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Attributes.Count; i++)
        {
            @await Html.PartialAsync("_ProviderAttribute", Model.Attributes[i])
        }
    }
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="+" formaction="AddAttribute" formmethod="post" />
    </div>
    <br/>
</form>
```

AddAttribute method simply adds new object to collection. Added Guid to make sure attributes are not the same.

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddAttribute(ProviderViewModel provider)
        {
            provider.Attributes.Add(new AttributeViewModel
            {
                Guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
            });
            return View(nameof(Provider), provider);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using javascript to add the new Attribute , the following is the demo I made ,you could  modify  according to your needs.

ViewModel

```
public class ProviderViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public List<AttributeViewModel> Attributes { get; set; }
}

public class AttributeViewModel
{
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

The main view , **Edit: use a hidden input to record the index value of the new Attribute item and the calculation of the index value is implemented in js**

```
@model WebAppDemo.Models.ViewModels.ProviderViewModel

<form asp-action="Create" method="post">
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Url)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Url)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.Label("Attributes")
</div>
<div class="attribute">
   <input hidden id="index" value="0"/>
   // render partial view
</div>

<div>
    <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="+" />
</div>
<br />
</form>

@section Scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
       var num = document.getElementById("index").value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "/Home/AddAttribute?index=" + num,
            success: function (result) {
                $(".attribute").append(result);
                num++;
                document.getElementById("index").value = num;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

AddAttribute method , **Edit: use ViewBag to save index**

```
public IActionResult AddAttribute(string index)
    {
        ViewBag.Index = index;
        ProviderViewModel provider = new ProviderViewModel {
            Attributes=new List<AttributeViewModel>()
        };
        provider.Attributes.Add(new AttributeViewModel
        {
            Guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        });
        return PartialView("_ProviderAttribute", provider);
    }
```

The _ProviderAttribute Partial View ,**Edit :for bind Attributes list to the ProviderViewModel from view to controller , define the name attribute of input as follows:**

```
@model WebAppDemo.Models.ViewModels.ProviderViewModel
@{
  ViewData["Title"] = "_ProviderAttribute";
 }
<div class="atrritem">
    <input name="Attributes[@ViewBag.Index].Guid" asp-for="Attributes[0].Guid" class="form-control" />
    <input name="Attributes[@ViewBag.Index].Name" asp-for="Attributes[0].Name" class="form-control" />
    <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but this doesn't add new Attribute to model bind to View, so when I'd like to submit form with filled forms it's not going to be visible in bound model, isn't it?